# Detect non-empty string with regexp?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

How do I write a PHP regexp which detects that a string is not empty?

Empty means, in this case 0 characters. A single space, or a single newline counts as not empty, for instance.

(It has to be regexp suitable for preg_match(), since I have a lookup table with various regexps and don't want to handle this case in any special way, it would complicate the code to not use a regexp here.)

---

I also can not use any regex modifiers such as "s" outside the `//` for sad reasons.

Comment: Why don't you want to handle this in any special way?

Comment: "..only spaces count as not empty.." - so, strings that don't have spaces??

Comment: Any string goes, except 0 length ones...

Comment: Sorry misread and gave the opposite of what you needed :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Well, obviously 99% of coders wouldn't use a regex for that, but since he has his own reasons for wanting a regex, let's respect it...

Comment: @PeeHaa, need and need. With regexp = code equal complexity and size. Without regexp = code with existing loop over a bunch of regexps + extra if-case for this value I am testing. Kludgy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
/[\s\S]/
```

matches any character, even if you can't use the `/s` modifier.

You don't need a quantifier (`+`) because if one character matches, then the condition is already fulfilled.

Comment: Short & to the point! You might add a comment about the inline `(?s)`? Or not, of course :)

Answer (score 7):

Just an idea (matches at least 1 of anything) :

```
/.{1,}/
```

- or, even shorter version (as @tigrang suggested) : `/.+/`
- or, even more complete version (including @BartKiers suggestion for `newline` support) where the `s` modifier causes the `.` meta char to match `\r` and `\n` as well:

  ```
  /.+/s
  ```

Comment: By default, `.` does not match a line break char. So `preg_match('/.+/', "\n")` will fail (return 0).

Comment: @BartKiers Good point too, though I was not sure if the OP really cared about newline chars...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon, well, since the OP mentioned a single white *not* being empty, I'd imagine a single line break being the same. I'd say `""` would be the empty string, everything else is not.

Comment: @BartKiers makes sense... (just updated my post to cover that scenario as well) ;-)

Comment: I took the liberty to also account for `\r`. And to be really nit-picky, you don't even need the `+` in there: only `/./s` is sufficient :)

Comment: @BartKiers, thank you, just newline also counts as a string. Your assumption is correct.  You have been so helpful it feels like nitpicking, but is there a way to match newlines without the s?  Something like /[.|\n|\r]+/ perhaps?

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Just follow the latest edit to my post by BartKiers... ;-)

Comment: That would be `/(.|[\r\n])/`. The `+` is completely redundant; your question is "is there at least obe character" and if there is, this regex will match.

Comment: If you really want the shortest possible regex then @Bart Kiers has it.

Comment: @BoltClock, except I can not use the modifier `s` to the meta char `.`

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, both `/[\s\S]/` and `/(?s)./` are the same as `/./s`.

Comment: Thanks for keeping the Q/A warm, all of you. :-)  I upvoted instantly of course. I think between these two answers and all the comments, I think we covered most there is to know about matching non-empty strings in regex :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Character class with exclusive and complete classes: `/[\w\W]/`, `/[\s\S]/`, `/[\d\D]/`.
2. Negative look-ahead on end of string: `/(?!=\z)/` or `/(?!=$)/D`
3. Unicode `Any` class: `/\p{Any}/u`, also matches newline
4. Period in *single-line* mode: `/./s`
5. Alteration of `.` and newline: `/.|\n/`