# Check empty input form

Tags: php, regex

How to check empty input form when submit by filter_var()

I want to use **filter_validate_regexp** function,but don't know **regexp** pattern to check empty fields.

```
$cond = filter_var(
    $_GET['name'],
    FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,  
    array(
        'options' => array('regexp'=>'???')
    )
) ? true : false;
```

Comment: You mean `^$`?? This is a regex for an empty string. Non-empty - `^[\s\S]+$`.

Comment: Why not use the function `empty($_GET['name'])` ?

Comment: Yes ,I want to check regexp pattern .:) @Patrick2607

Answer (score 1):

For checking if a value is not empty, guess you mean something having a value, just a `if` would do.

`if ($_GET['name'])`

Answer (score 1):

[Detect non-empty string with regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050295/detect-non-empty-string-with-regexp)

```
/[\s\S]/
```

Is this what were you looking for?

EDIT:

```
$_GET['name'] == null --> $cond = false
$_GET['name'] == false --> $cond = false
$_GET['name'] == true --> $cond = true
$_GET['name'] == '' --> $cond = false
$_GET['name'] == ' ' --> $cond = true
$_GET['name'] == 'anystring' --> $cond = true
```

Comment: I think you are missing a qualifier. Shouldn't there be a * qualifier after the character class?

Comment: You don't need the repetition since the _$cond_ becomes _true_ with first character found. I've tested it and it works without quantifier.

Comment: Yes quantifier. But doesn't that allow something like " x" ? The first char is and empty space but the input contains non white space.

Comment: Yes _" x"_ returns _true_. That's bad? I'm sorry, maybe I just didn't understand the question. However, when you are fetching a 'name' from $_GET, you don't mind that first or last character is " ", do you? You can use `$name = trim( $_GET['name'] )`.